# Windows Activation in Amazon EC2

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, activation

I'm trying to activate Windows 2008 Server in Amazon EC2 as described here:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=185874#185874

I'm trying these two amazon addresses, for my server's region:

`ec2-174-129-233-152.compute-1.amazonaws.com`
`ec2-174-129-233-141.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

I get success when I run:  `slmgr.vbs /skms ec2-174-129-233-152.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

The I get a `0xC004F039` error upon running:  `slmgr.vbs /ato`

`slmgr.vbs /dli` shows:

`Registered KMS machine name: ec2-174-129-233-152.compute-1.amazonaws.com:1688`

I can't ping:

`ec2-174-129-233-152.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-174-129-233-152.compute-1.amazonaws.com:1688

174.129.233.152

14.129.233.152:1688`

But I can ping `google.com`

The time is synced to a server which can activate without any problems, so incorrect request timestamp shouldn't be an issue.

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running a local DNS server?

I found that even if you tell IPv4 to use DHCP for its DNS server, Windows will prefer the IPv6 server on ::1.  Check by running 'nslookup'.

After making that change, I changed the EC2WindowsActivate plugin and restarted the service, and it activated correctly.